# Managing rollback on transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I've a problem with the annotation `@Transactional`.

I've a method doing some stuff, and inside I throw and catch an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I think ( even if i've caught the exception ) that it sets the transaction as rollbackOnly ( some trigger on the throws of exception ) and it ends without succeeding to commit the transaction.

Here is the error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException : Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

I could add on the `@Transactional` a no-rollback-for the exception I throw and catch, but i don't think it's a real solution.

Maybe there is a way to unset the rollbackOnly on the transaction but I don't think that it's the best practice too...

So, do you have any idea how should i do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Try / catch with `IllegalArgumentException` sounds like a code smell (Effective Java item 57: [Use Exceptions only for exceptional conditions](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/exceptions/ch09lev1sec1))
2. Whether the transaction is set to `rollbackOnly` depends on the proxy mechanism used. If you use JDK proxies, the handler sits outside and has no way to register a caught exception inside the method call. If you use `mode=aspectj`, things will be different. Also, if you have nested transactional contexts, you will have to use `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=IllegalArgumentException.class)` on the inner method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ( I can only read a part of the link you gave ), and I don't really get whether you're talking about not using Exceptions in my case in general, or not using Runtime exception. NB: ( i'm using an exception to warn of an error that is thrown from some classes to other classes )

Comment: @RoD you should read the Effective Java book, it's the one book every Java developer should read. But to understand this specific aspect, you can read any of the articles returned by this search: [exceptions "flow control"](http://www.google.com/search?q=exceptions+%22flow+control%22)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't commit the transaction then you probably have an exception in your code. By doing a try/catch, you conceal the full exception, and simply get a delicate generic explanation. You also get a rollback.

In order to understand your mistake, and to get the full description of your error, try to drop the try/catch thing and let the code explode. There you will see the real source of your problem.